# Export Html table into Excel

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, javascript, jsom, sp.js

I have written the code in .JS file to fetch the data from sharepoint list and display in html table.

Now to take my work for next level I need to export the html table to "Excel".
The below code is working fine in google chrome,But I find no luck in IE browser

Can any one help me for what reasons the below code is not getting execute

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnExport").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //getting data from our table
    var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';
    var table_div = document.getElementById('table_wrapper');
    var table_html = table_div.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');

    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = data_type + ', ' + table_html;
    a.download = 'exported_table_' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 9999999) + 1000000) + '.xls';
    a.click();
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="btnExport">Export to xls</button>
  <br />
  <br />
  <div id="table_wrapper">
    <table border="1" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#222" id="list">
      <tbody>
        <tr class="header">
          <th>user_id</th>
          <th>firstname</th>
          <th>lastname</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Alex</td>
          <td>Lahevin</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Kostas</td>
          <td>Krevatas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>Alexander</td>
          <td>Fakaris</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why build the html when you can directly build the Excel file?
For example with: xlsx.js

Comment: I am using the above JavaScript in my js.file .Using the html file for presenting in stack echange. My problem is with above javascript which is not working in IR browser

Comment: No the above code requíres the html otherwise you will get a empty Excel file. Which begs the qeustion why build the html and fetch when you can just build the Excel directly.

Comment: can you please suggest is any alternative way to use in .js which helps in exporting the html table data in excel

Comment: can you use ActiveX?

Answer (score 2):

`a.download` is not supported in IE and Mozilla browser.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=download